# Downloaded Xcode updated version,but not showing it in the Application folder

Tags: xcode7

I have tried downloading Xcode 7.3.2.Xcode 7.1 was already there in the system.[image: Appstore Xcode status]

But in Application folder nothing new is there.Only Xcode 7.1 is available.In App Store if I search for this particular Xcode 7.3.2 , it is showing like the above screenshot.And I am able to open Xcode from there.Kindly please guide me on this..Thank you very much in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you updated your Xcode 7.1 to 7.3.2 and somehow expected that the 7.3.2 will be installed side-by-side with the older one. If you want to have multiple Xcode versions on your system you need to manually download older version you need [from here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/).

Comment: Thanks Lawicko for your quick response. In this link I didn't see Xcode 7.3.2 , and can see only 7.3.1. I wanted to upgrade xcode 7.1 to Xcode 7.3.2.But now only 7.1 is  available in my mac.

Comment: @iOSManiac ok than I misunderstood your original question. I'm not sure where did you come up with the Xcode 7.3.2 from, I just checked the store and the official version is 7.3.1. So if you still have 7.1 then I'd suggest opening store once again and check for updates. Otherwise, I'm not sure what to think about this.